# NullPointerException error when trying to add to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, bluej

Trying to add the object member to the ArrayList loggedInList when logging into the Website class.

```
public class Website
{
// The name of the website.
private String name;
// The number of hits on the website.
public int hits;
// The amount of money taken at the checkout.
private double salesTotal;
// 
private ArrayList<Member> loggedInList;
```

Is the code for my Website class.

```
    public Website(String newName)
{
    // Intialises the name of the website.
    name = newName;
    // Intialises the number of hits on the site.
    hits = 0;
    // Intialises the amount of money taken at the checkout.
    salesTotal = 0;
    // 
    loggedInList = new ArrayList<Member>();


}
```

Is the constructor for the Website class.

```
    public void memberLogin(Member member)
{
    member.setLoginStatus(true);
    member.setWebsite(this);

    System.out.println(name + " welcomes member " + member.getMembershipNumber() + "," + " you are now logged in.");

    member.setWebsite(this);

    hits +=1;

    loggedInList.add(member);
}
```

Is the method which SHOULD add the current member into the ArrayList.

The error I get is a NullPointerException on the line:

```
loggedInList.add(member);
```

I honestly have no clue why.

Comment: construct the list before using it

Comment: ^ it looks like they are doing that from the code pasted ...

Comment: Either list is null or member is null

Comment: Could you explain what you mean? I'm very new to Java and BlueJ etc so I'm at really basic level

Comment: This is a strange post because member wouldn't be null if the exception is happening on the line the OP describes...

Comment: Where else in your class do you do anything with `loggedInList`?  Perhaps you're setting it to `null` sometime after construction?  The code you've posted should work.  Can you [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]?  Perhaps you're not calling the code you think you are...

Comment: Guys, it's perfectly valid to add `null` to an `ArrayList`, so that couldn't be it anyway.  `loggedInList` must be null.

Comment: `loggedInList` must be getting reinstantiated post-construction somewhere else in `Website`

Comment: Also @jd123, you should have your class member `loggedInList` be a `List<Member>` rather than an `ArrayList<Member>`. This is called "programming to the interface" and is probably a little more advanced than you're ready for. But make note of it for the future to look into.

Comment: I decided to vote this question as duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384) because despite that we can't reproduce this problem, solution is still same as in duplicate: ensure that `loggedInList` is initialized properly before using `loggedInList.add(..)`. This can be done at declaration level `private ArrayList<Member> loggedInList = new ArrayList<>();` which will ensure that this list will always be initialized, unless OP in different place will explicitly set it to null.

Comment: @azurefrog I don't use loggedInList anywhere else, its new. I created it along with the ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are not using the correct constructor. You may have a default no arg constructor in your code.

In any case, you should do it similar to the code below.

```
   Website website = new Website ("someString value");
website.memberLogin (objectCreatedMember);
```

Comment: [Your recent deleted post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59084027/problem-using-firebase-db-connect-to-spring-project) is not an acceptable use of Stack Overflow. If you want to experiment, there is a sandbox page on meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox